# Export joomla user with same password

Tags: joomla, migration, export

I am merging a small group on sort of site with my joomla site. I already have members in my joomla site so I somehow want to migrate the users of joomla to groupon database which uses a different encryption scheme for password. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to have the unencrypted passwords to be able to use that. There is no conversion from one encryption scheme to another.